# Exclude empty fields from Log4J2 JsonTemplateLayout output

Tags: log4j2

The log4j2 [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) offers a `%notEmpty` conversion pattern that allows you to skip sections of the pattern that refer to empty variables.

Is there any way to do something similar for [JsonTemplateLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html), specifically for thread context data ([MDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#map-resolver-template))? It correctly (IMO) suppresses null fields, but it doesn't do the same with empty ones.

E.g., given the following in my JSON template:

```json
"application": {
  "name":     { "key": "x-app", "$resolver": "mdc" },
  "context":  { "key": "x-app-context", "$resolver": "mdc" },
  "instance": {
    "name":    { "key": "x-appinst", "$resolver": "mdc" },
    "context": { "key": "x-appinst-context", "$resolver": "mdc" }
  }
}
```

is there a way to prevent blocks like this from being logged, where the only data in the subtree is the empty string values for `context`?

```json
"application":{"context":"","instance":{"context":""}}
```

(Yes, ideally I'd prevent those empty strings being put into the context in the first place, but this isn't my app, I'm just configuring it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonTemplateLayout` author speaking here. Currently, `JsonTemplateLayout` doesn't support *blank property exclusion* for the following reasons:

1. The definition of empty/blank is ambiguous. One might have, `null`, `{}`, `"\s*"`, `[]`, `[[]]`, `[{}]`, etc. as valid JSON values. Which one of these are empty/blank? Let's assume we have agreed on a certain behavior. Will it apply to the rest of its users?
2. Checking if a value is empty/blank incurs an extra runtime cost.
3. Most of the time you don't care. You persist logs in a storage system, e.g., ELK stack, and there blank value elimination is provided out of the box by the storage engine in the most efficient way.

Would you mind sharing your use case, please? **Why** do you want to prevent the emission of `"context": ""` properties? If you deliver your logs to Elasticsearch, there you can easily exclude such fields via appropriate index mappings.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working with a vendor product that puts about forty values in the thread context, but depending on the type of log event, only about eight or ten are populated in any given message. As you say, if I pipe the logs to Elasticsearch or similar, I can filter it there, but currently we're not, & it would be nice if the JSON was more or less human-readable when we're just glancing at it in Cloudwatch. We can live with it for now, and if we can't there's probably a [ScriptAppenderSelector](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ScriptAppenderSelector) solution.

Comment: @DavidMoles, okay, makes sense. I have created [LOG4J2-3053](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3053) to address this issue.

Comment: @DavidMoles, there is actually an optimization in the `ReadOnlyStringMapResolver#createKeyResolver()` (used by `ThreadContextDataResolver`, aka MDC resolver) that ignores _non-existing keys_. Hence, I am curious how come your _blank_ MDC values are rendered. Is it correct that in your cases MDC keys do exist, but they map to empty strings?

Comment: yep, as far as I can tell the vendor's code is either putting empty strings in the ThreadContext or some sort of placeholder object with an empty string representation. :( It's not for everything in the map, thankfully, or the output would be a lot noisier!

Answer (score 0):

Near as I can tell, no. I would suggest you create a Jira issue to get that addressed.